# How to call a particular div using html hyperlink

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I want to call a particular `div` using a hyperlink.  Here is my code:

```
 <div id="mainNavPane">
    <ul id="sideSubNav">

        <li><a href="#" class="prim">Individuals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="view">Individuals1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="mainScrollPane">
```

```
  <!-- 1-5 -->
  <div id="homeScreen" class="screen">
     <div class="arrowLeft" style="width:50px;"><a class="prev"><img src="../images/btn-ArrowPrev.gif"/></a></div>
    <img src="images/bg-HomeScreen.jpg" height=50px width=50px />
     <div class="arrowRight" style="width:50px;"><a class="next"><img src="../images/btn-ArrowNext.gif" /></a></div>
  </div>

   <!-- 5-10 -->
  <div id="IndividualsScreen" class="screen">
     <h2>Individuals using Breaking Free Online</h2>
     <div class="arrowLeft" style="width:50px;"><a class="prev"><img src="../images/btn-ArrowPrev.gif" /></a></div>
     <div class="screenBody" style="width:460px;">
      <ul>
          <li>If you are struggling to control your drinking or use of drugs, Breaking Free Online
              offers you treatment that is immediate, confidential and effective – even if your
              dependence is severe and has been for a long time </li>
          <li>You can take advantage of the treatment at home or anywhere with an internet connection,
              and at the times that are most convenient for you, because it is available online
              24 hours a day </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowRight" style="width:50px;"><a class="next"><img src="../images/btnArrowNext.gif" /></a></div>
  </div>   
    </div>
```

I want to display `div id = individualscreen` when `<a href="#" class="prim">Individuals</a>` hyperlink is clicked similarly when the `<a href="#" class="view">Individuals1</a>` should show `div id=homescreen`

Comment: Do you want to have the `div` hidden to begin with and then display it when you click the link, or do you just want the page to jump to the `div` when you click the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a # followed by the id of the element: `href="#individualscreen"`

Comment: @Muhammad Awais: that should work... [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/3Yqwt/).

Comment: your example is working , but i dunno y the same thing is not working in my case may be the javascript or css is conflicting as I am using scrollable screens

Comment: @Muhammad Awais: That example doesn't use JavaScript or CSS so there shouldn't be a conflict...

Comment: yeh it seems to be working now , just a quick query , what about if i want to hide particular div on clicking certain html tags and enabling that divs on clicking different hyperlinks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to the `div`, you can follow David Dorward's example.

If you want to hide/show the `div` when the link is clicked, you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#prim').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#individualscreen').toggle();
  });
});
```