# Getting a link to load a page half way down

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site and I have a page full of links, What I would like to happen is when one of those links is clicked, the browser will load a new page but only the relevent section of that page..

Does anybody have any idea of how this can be achieved?

I have used this method on one page only before, so that when a link at the top is clicked it will take you further down.. But can this also be done with an external link?

Comment: you have to load the data from external link in your page section where you want to show

Comment: you mean to say like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935642/how-to-call-a-particular-div-using-html-hyperlink) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a link :

```
<a href="#" class="mylink">Link</a>
```

Then change to :

```
<a href="#linktodiv" class="mylink">Link</a>
```

And

You should have to add `id="linktodiv"` to the div to show when link is clicked.

For more info [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935642/how-to-call-a-particular-div-using-html-hyperlink)